# Create a list of clickable links in a Helper module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, view-helpers, helpermethods

A user has a set of saved links.

Each link has the properties `address` and `text`. These can be accessed like so:

```
@user.links.first.address
@user.links.first.text
```

**How would I generate a list of `a` tags for all links that a user has saved in a helper method, that I can call from a view?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with

```
def create_links
 html=""
 @user.links.each do |link|
  html += link_to "Link for #{link.address}", "#"
  html += link_to "Link for #{link.text}", "#"
 end
  html.html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do a `.each` on the `@user.links`?

You could do this:

```
<% @user.links.each do |link| %>
    <%= link_to link.text, link.address %>
<% end %>
```

This would negate the requirement of loading a helper

Comment: It's true that this would normally be the "easiest" way to go. In my case I have conditionals involved in the loop which would clutter the view a bit too much, hence why I'd like to use a helper.

Answer (score 1):

You use this code

```
 def directory(links)
    links.inject([]) {|_, e| _ << link_to e.name, e.address; _ }.join.html_safe
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I expressed myself not clearly enough, because both answers uses `link.address` and `link.text` in a way I don't quite understand. But it gave me enough info to solve it myself. This is how I did it:

```
def link_generator(user_links)
  html = ""
  user_links.each do |link|
    html += link_to link.name, link.address
  end
  html.html_safe
end
```